# get ipallowlist in innodb cluster

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am new to innodb cluster and while setting up the innodb cluster, there is a step to setup `ipAllowlist`

```
c.addInstance("cluster_admin@service_name_of_new_node:3306",{ipAllowlist: "node1_service_name,new_node_service_name,...all_existing_service_names_in_this_cluster", recoveryMethod:"clone"});
```

How do you retrieve the current ipAllowlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 cluster = dba.getCluster()
 cluster.options()
```